# Getting the selected year from textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get my SQL to pick up a year selected in text48 - So if they select year 2016 the SQL will only show accounts in the year 2016.

Below is my SQL:

```
SELECT tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Mail Date], 
       tbl_ComplaintsCoded.[Account Number], 
       tbl_ComplaintsCoded.Advisors
FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded
WHERE Year([Mail Date])=Year([text48].[value]) AND 
      Advisors=[forms]![frm_Central_Reporting_Ops]![Text52]);
```

I cant work out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user selects a *year*, it should just read:

```
WHERE Year([Mail Date])=[text48].[value]
```

or rather:

```
WHERE Year([Mail Date])=[text48]
```

or perhaps:

```
WHERE Year([Mail Date])=[Forms]![frm_Central_Reporting_Ops]![text48]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed my SQL as per the post but getting Syntax error still